# nagios configuration make error

Tags: make, nagios3

I'm configuring nagios on ubuntu 14.04. 
When I use this command inside downloads:

```
make all
```

Appear this error:

```
make: * * * No rule to make target 'all'. Stop.
```

Any solutions?

Comment: You dont need to implement difficult methods for install nagios. it is in Main ubuntu repo and can be installed as `sudo apt-get install nagios3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to implement difficult methods for install nagios.

It is in [Main ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nagios3) and can be installed as

```
sudo apt-get install nagios3 nagios3-cgi nagios3-core
```

You can install plugins and related packages with :

```
sudo apt-get install check-mk-config-nagios3 ganglia-nagios-bridge gosa-plugin-nagios gosa-plugin-nagios-schema libnagios-plugin-perl nagios-images nagios-nrpe-plugin nagios-nrpe-server nagios-plugin-check-multi nagios-plugins nagios-plugins-basic nagios-plugins-common nagios-plugins-contrib nagios-plugins-extra nagios-plugins-openstack nagios-plugins-standard nagios-snmp-plugins nagios3-cgi nagios3-common nagios3-core nagios3-dbg nagios3-doc ndoutils-nagios3-mysql pnp4nagios pnp4nagios-bin pnp4nagios-web
```